# Old C# project pushed to repository, but fails compiling because missing DLLs in VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013, gitblit

Last year an ex-employee pushed a Visual Studio project to our GitBlit repository, but once I checked it out and tried to compile it, it says

> Error 51  Metadata file 'D:\GIT\epimst\MSTDAO\bin\Debug\MSTDAO.dll' could not be found    D:\GIT\epimst\EPIMST\CSC    EPIMST
>
> Error 47  Metadata file 'D:\GIT\epimst\EPIDAO\bin\Debug\EPIDAO.dll' could not be found    D:\GIT\epimst\epiapputils\CSC   epiapputils
>
> Error 48  Metadata file 'D:\GIT\epimst\EPIDAO\bin\Debug\EPIDAO.dll' could not be found    D:\GIT\epimst\MSTDAO\CSC    MSTDAO
>
> Error 50  Metadata file 'D:\GIT\epimst\EPIDAO\bin\Debug\EPIDAO.dll' could not be found    D:\GIT\epimst\EPIMST\CSC    EPIMST

So my solution was to copy these DLLs from our deployed software and simply copy them back into their various directories. This fixed the 'count not be found' errors, but then a host of undefined code errors came up.

[image]

Seeing as how this code did work at some point and the live packages still function, I cant figure out what went wrong between the code being checked in and eventually checked out by me.

Unfortunately we cant get in touch with that one employee that pushed up the code, and I've spent a few days reading about changing target frameworks, output options, build settings, etc, but none of them fix the dependencies problems or missing DLLs.

We are almost positive the DLLs are from the same version as we only released one version of the software, but somehow the source code no longer works.

Comment: Does the solution contain projects with the same names as the missing files?  If one project fails to build for any reason, the failure can cascade through all the dependent projects.

Comment: I wonder if you could not locate the necessary dll's remove the existing reference to them and set the CopyLocal` property = true then when you build the projects at least the dll's will pull into the bin directory..

Comment: @MethodMan I tried removing the references and re-adding them with coylocal set to True, but it didn't seem to change anything; without my copied DLLs theres still reference errors, with them theres still the compiling errors.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you are listing the errors out of sequence.  This suggests that you have made a common mistake which is especially critical when bringing up a solution in a new environment:

- You are reading the tabular "Error List" window rather than the compiler output.

[image: Comparison of Build Output window with Error List window]

This is bad for two reasons:

1. The compiler output contains additional information related to the compile and often related to the errors.  But all non-error messages get stripped by the IDE and don't appear in the "Error List" window.
2. The first messages are the most important, because later errors are often side effects of the first few.

Switch to the "Output" window, make sure the setting is "Show output from: Build", scroll to the top, and start addressing errors in the order of occurrence.

The most likely possibility is that the coder forgot to check in *one* file, resulting in errors in that project where other files used that class.  Then since that project didn't build, all the dependent projects can't find *anything* that's contained in that or any other dependent project, resulting in hundreds of errors.  Which is really hard to sort out in the Error List, but perfectly clear when you switch to the actual Build Output log.

Comment: I tried rebuilding and looked at the Build output, but I dont see any missing file errors, just the same errors that were displayed in the Error List.

Comment: @Zorgarath: Please add the first errors that appear in build output, as an edit to your question.

Comment: I took a screenshot of the build errors (the first handful were warnings) and added the link to my question.

Comment: @Zorgarath: Well, what data type does `EPIDAO.data.basic.DataValue` have?  Normally `GetValueOrDefault` is associated with `Nullable` types.  Missing extension methods could indeed be caused by an entire missing file as I guessed, luckily it is not too difficult to guess how `GetValueOrDefault` should be defined.  Is it being called with any arguments?

Comment: My concern isnt so much how to troubleshoot each problem, but rather why there are problems in the first place, where did the errors come from? The code was deployed successfully a while ago, then pushed to GIT and checked out, and now theres errors.

Comment: @Zorgarath: Either not all the files were pushed to GIT, or you checked out the wrong branch